# VSTS PBI creation via Azure DevOps Python API

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-api-apps

Creating a program that will automatically create PBIs in AzureDevOps for my organization. I cant quite figure out how to make a script reference the APIs AzureDevOps have created. I'm simply wanting to have the program take my token and create a work item in vsts and assign it to myself with a customized title. I have installed azure CLI and have downloaded the azure-devops-python-samples files, but theres not a good way for me to reference a way to create_work_item. I guess I need a tutorial on how to take the [github files](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-samples) and simply have another program reference this way of making a PBI. I'm fairly new to all of this, so someone that can explain how to do this would be really helpful!

TLDR: Point A - Have a title and user_assignment saved as variables in another file
Point B - Reference these variables and make a PBI for my org.

I figure it would be helpful to have my code in this question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import base64
import json
import requests
#from bugcrowdapipull.py import xbug_title


pat = 'PAT HERE'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
url="https://PROJECT.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response)


def create_work_item(self, document, project, type='Bug', validate_only=None, bypass_rules=None, suppress_notifications=None, expand=None):
        """CreateWorkItem.
        [Preview API] Creates a single work item.
        :param :class:`<[JsonPatchOperation]> <azure.devops.v6_0.work_item_tracking.models.[JsonPatchOperation]>` document: The JSON Patch document representing the work item
        :param str project: Project ID or project name
        :param str type: The work item type of the work item to create
        :param bool validate_only: Indicate if you only want to validate the changes without saving the work item
        :param bool bypass_rules: Do not enforce the work item type rules on this update
        :param bool suppress_notifications: Do not fire any notifications for this change
        :param str expand: The expand parameters for work item attributes. Possible options are { None, Relations, Fields, Links, All }.
        :rtype: :class:`<WorkItem> <azure.devops.v6_0.work_item_tracking.models.WorkItem>`
        """
        route_values = {}
        if project is not None:
            route_values['project'] = self._serialize.url('project', project, 'str')
        if type is not None:
            route_values['type'] = self._serialize.url('type', type, 'str')
        query_parameters = {}
        if validate_only is not None:
            query_parameters['validateOnly'] = self._serialize.query('validate_only', validate_only, 'bool')
        if bypass_rules is not None:
            query_parameters['bypassRules'] = self._serialize.query('bypass_rules', bypass_rules, 'bool')
        if suppress_notifications is not None:
            query_parameters['suppressNotifications'] = self._serialize.query('suppress_notifications', suppress_notifications, 'bool')
        if expand is not None:
            query_parameters['$expand'] = self._serialize.query('expand', expand, 'str')
        content = self._serialize.body(document, '[JsonPatchOperation]')
        response = self._send(http_method='POST',
                              location_id='62d3d110-0047-428c-ad3c-4fe872c91c74',
                              version='6.0-preview.3',
                              route_values=route_values,
                              query_parameters=query_parameters,
                              content=content,
                              media_type='application/json-patch+json')
        return self._deserialize('WorkItem', response)


print('\n\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both [python api client library](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) and Restful api to create a work items. Please check below examples:

1, Use python api client library. Please check [create_work_item](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/v5_1/work_item_tracking/work_item_tracking_client.py#L1578) method for more information.

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v5_1.py_pi_api import JsonPatchOperation

token = 'PAT'
team_instance = 'https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}'
credentials = BasicAuthentication("", token)
connection = Connection(base_url=team_instance, creds=credentials)

wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

def createworkitem():
    documents = []

    # add title field
    documents.append(JsonPatchOperation(from_=None,op='add',path="/fields/System.Title",value="i am created by python client"))
    # add assignTo field
    documents.append(JsonPatchOperation(from_=None,op='add',path="/fields/System.AssignedTo",value="User DisplayName"))

    result = wit_client.create_work_item(documents, "{ProjectName}", 'Product Backlog Item', validate_only=None, bypass_rules=None, suppress_notifications=None, expand=None)
    print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   createworkitem()
```

2, Use Restful API, [Work Item- Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)：

```
import requests
import base64

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pat = '{PAT}'
    authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json', #specify the content-type
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
    } 

    url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=5.1"

    body = [{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
     "value": "Sample from python api"
    },
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
     "value": "User Name"
    }]

    response = requests.post(url, json = body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Second one seems to be working a lot better for me, but I dont think I have my url quite right. mine is a 'xxxllc-dev.visualstudio.com/ ' type link. I cant figure out where I'm supposed to find my link similar to yours but I dont think it shuould be azure.com. Am I wrong thinking this?

Comment: dev.azure.com is the new domain name, but you can still use the old one visualstudio.com. Please check out the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch#switch-existing-organizations-to-use-the-new-domain-name-url)

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong then. My url seems correct. I can get 200 responses. But I cant seem to create a pbi with this code. Any idea? The url is '{org}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit?workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=5.1'

Seems right to me. No PBI is being formed though.

Comment: You need to refresh your azure devops page to show up the new work item.

Comment: Not showing up. I'll even search for the title i put on it with nothing showing.

Comment: Is the "?" in above url `wit?workitems` a typo, or it was actually in your url? Please also try creating a different work item type(ie. Bug) to check if it returns the same result.

Comment: /_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=5.1
is what I have, my mistake. I have also tried Bug instead of Product Backlog Item.

I'm really wondering what I am doing wrong. I dont think it could be my credentials on vsts, because I can make PBIs manually, and I get a 200 response so I can connect...

Comment: Could you check if you can view the edit page for the newly created PBI. `'{org}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_workitems/edit/{PBI workitem id}/`. You can get the new created PBI id from the post request response. If not. i suggest you report this issue to [Dev Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and have your project checked by Microsoft development team.

Comment: Ok so I just didnt have the right credentials. I got it to work, thanks for your help.